# Sed/Awk remove entire section between 2 markes after a pattern match

Tags: awk, sed

Given a TCL script that has multiple if conditions in the following format:

```
if { $var1 == "string1" || $var2 == "string2" ... } {
   line1
   line2
   line3
   ...
} else {
   line10
   line11
}
```

I'm looking to find every if statements where string1 appears in the condition, remove the if condition and leave only the lines in the else branch. In the example above the expected result will be:

```
line10
line11
```

Comment: ***every** if statements*? - your code has only one such `if` stmt

Comment: In the example above I have included only one but the file can have multiple **if** similar to that where string1 is used for conditional checking

Comment: What about nested `if`s? And nested `if`s that have `string1` in condition?

Comment: Assume that there are no nested _if s_  and won't be any. All the conditionals are very similar to the one above.

Comment: And what do `linex` look like? Complex commands, or?

Comment: `linex` consists only in assignments of the type: `set some_var = "some text" `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably be better off using a real TCL parser for this, but here's an `awk` script (basically a simple state machine) that handles the simple case you presented:

```
awk '/if.*string1/ {inif=1;next}
     inif && /\}\s*else\s*\{/ {inif=0;inelse=1;next}
     inif && /\}/ {inif=0;next}
     inelse && /\}/ {inelse=0;next}
     inelse {sub(/\s*/,"")}
     !inif' file
```

Example input (extended sample from the question):

```
$ cat file
if { $var1 == "string1" || $var2 == "string2" ... } {
   line1
   line2
   line3
   ...
} else {
   line10
   line11
}

if { $var1 == "string1" || $var2 == "string2" ... } {
   line1
   line2=2
   line3="2";
   ...
} else {
   line11
   line12
}

if { $var1 == "string1" || $var2 == "string2" ... } {
   # matching if block without else is also removed
}

if { something else } {
    test
}
```

Result:

```
$ awk '/if.*string1/ {inif=1;next}  inif && /\}\s*else\s*\{/ {inif=0;inelse=1;next}  inelse && /\}/ {inelse=0;next}  inelse {sub(/\s*/,"")}  !inif' file
line10
line11

line11
line12


if { something else } {
    test
}
```

Comment: I can't make this work. I'm using exactly your file as test and on tcsh (mainly I need to work in cshell) I get: `Unmatched '.` then If I make a script in  #!/bin/sh, I get: `awk: warning: escape sequence `\}' treated as plain `}'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\s' treated as plain `s'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\{' treated as plain `{'
`

Comment: The above errors I've got in bash shell when I was running with -F option. If I remove the switch there is no output at all. Doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: It does seem to be shell/awk dependent. I only managed to get it work with Awk 4.1.3, under bash, version 4.3.48. Unfortunately on the machine I'm running I have Awk 3.1.7 and can't update.

Comment: Not sure about `awk` 3, but you can try running it like a script with hash bang `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` and the program in the next line `/if.*string1/ {inif=1;next}  inif && ...`. Also, you might try with `gawk`, maybe even install the newest version of `gawk`..

Comment: No worries, I have sort it out in the meantime. I have reverse engineer your script and slightly modified and now works on both versions. Also realized that in some cases I want to keep the if branch not else part so modified accordingly. All good now. Thank you!

Comment: @Birbal it helps to post the modified version, can save you some torn hair years on when you meet the same problem, search for hints, and bump into your own question and an indefinite "solved _a bit_ differently".  Been there, trust me :-)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelShigorin, for bringing me back to this answer. On inspection, I noticed one case wasn't handled properly (matching if without the else), so I fixed that. Thanks!